# Get closer to vs become intimate with

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, usage

1. *Get closer to* vs *get more closer to*

When do you say *get closer to* and can you say *get more closer to someone*?

Is it awkward to say *get more closer to someone*?

2. Can the phrase *become intimate with someone* - be interchangeable with *get closer to*?

I've just learnt that *become intimate with someone* has a more sexual meaning...

I would like to know the difference in usage and meaning between these phrases.

3. the word " intimate" usually use online??

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion,

1. **get closer** would be correct. Closer is already comparative. "More closer" would be ungrammatical.
   [close on Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close#Adjective)
2. **become intimate with someone**  is generally not interchangeable with **get closer to**.
   The adjective **intimate** already carries some physical and sexual meaning.
3. Well, you could use the word **intimate** with your friends if you are really close enough to feel that you can share your "intimate private life" with. 
   For example, I wouldn't use that word around new people you've just met at a friend's house-warming party.

Comment: Being 'intimate with' someone is often a euphemism for having a sexual relationship with them, but it doesn't have to be. Intimate friends are people you know very well; a restaurant has an intimate atmosphere if it's small and friendly.